# Getting value in VBscript from VBA Excel Macro Function

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

Fairly new to VBscript and VBA... hoping for some help and that it's an easy answer...

I'm calling a Macro / Function in Excel VBA from VBscript. The call to the Function should return a number. Using VBA debug in Excel, the function appears to work properly (in this example, it displays a value of 1), but when I call the Macro / Function and attempt to echo the value in VBscript it shows as "Empty".

How can I get the value from VBA back to VBscript?
Thanks for your help

Example of VBscript code:

```
Set excelOBJ = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set workbookOBJ = excelOBJ.Workbooks.Open("C:\variable.xlsm")

excelOBJ.Application.Visible = True
excelOBJ.DisplayAlerts = False

REM mostly for testing purposes
    Dim returnValue
    returnValue = 10

    Wscript.Echo "'returnValue' value before call to macro function = " & returnValue
    Wscript.Echo "'returnValue' TypeName before call to macro function = " & TypeName(returnValue)

returnValue = excelOBJ.Run("ThisWorkbook.getNum")

    Wscript.Echo "'returnValue' value after call to macro function = " & returnValue
    Wscript.Echo "'returnValue' TypeName after call to macro function = " & TypeName(returnValue)

excelOBJ.quit
```

Example of VBA in Excel:

```
Public Function getNum()
    getNum = 1
    Debug.Print "getNum value = " & getNum
End Function
```

Output:

```
'returnValue' value before call to macro function = 10
'returnValue' TypeName before call to macro function = Integer

REM Inside Excel VBA editor
    getNum value = 1

'returnValue' value after call to macro function = 
'returnValue' TypeName after call to macro function = Empty
```

Comment: Try `returnValue = excelOBJ.Run("'Variable.xlsm'!.getNum")`

Comment: Thanks, @PatricK. I tried changing the code as you described, but received the error "Cannot run the macro ''variable.xlsm'!.getNum'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."  Code:  800A03EC. after the first 2 Wscript.Echo windows. I verified that macros were enabled in the Excel spreadsheet, but still encounter the error

Comment: Is your macro in the Worksheet or in a Module? You might need to reference the Sheet name explicitly if the macro is not in a module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend moving your code to a module if not there already.

This code should be changed

```
returnValue = excelOBJ.Run("ThisWorkbook.getNum")
```

If code is in a worksheet, this might work assuming your Worksheet is "Sheet1"

```
returnValue = excelOBJ.Run("Sheet1.getNum")
```

Otherwise if it's in a Module, simply use module name

```
returnValue = excelOBJ.Run("Module1.getNum")
```

If it starts running with this change but you're not getting anything returned you can change your function to pass `return value parameter ByRef` and check it that way

Comment: Thank you @dbmitch - I was hoping for a simple solution and this seems to be it. Before, the code was in "VBA Project (Variable.xlsm) > Microsoft Excel Objects > This Workbook".  After creating a Module ("VBA Project (Variable.xlsm) > Modules > Module1"), placing the code in the Module, and changing the "Run" argument to "Module1.getNum", it runs properly. The value 1 and TypeName of Integer are returned and displayed. Thank you!